# Excel - move a whole row into the next worksheet if cell contains specific text

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, vbscript

I am trying to set up a formula where worksheet 1 is a list of install jobs for the month, there are several columns showing customers details and at the last column showing the progress of the job from a drop down list.

If the job is "completed" then I would like the entire row to be copied into the next worksheet (worksheet 2) and if the job is in progress then it does not go onto the next worksheet.

i also have several failed reasons would it be possible to have a this data transferred to (worksheet 3) to show a list of filed jobs from sheet 1

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to copy a line in excel using a specific word and pasting to another excel sheet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11631363/how-to-copy-a-line-in-excel-using-a-specific-word-and-pasting-to-another-excel-s)

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub copyJobs()
  Dim r1
  Dim r2
  Dim r3
  r1 = 1
  r2 = 1
  r3 = 1
  While Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & LTrim(Str(r1))) <> ""
    If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & LTrim(Str(r1))) = "completed" Then
      Sheets("Sheet1").Range(LTrim(Str(r1)) & ":" & LTrim(Str(r1))).Copy
      Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & LTrim(Str(r2))).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
      r2 = r2 + 1
    End If
    If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & LTrim(Str(r1))) = "failed" Then
      Sheets("Sheet1").Range(LTrim(Str(r1)) & ":" & LTrim(Str(r1))).Copy
      Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & LTrim(Str(r3))).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
      r3 = r3 + 1
    End If
    r1 = r1 + 1
  Wend
End Sub
```

It will start with row 1 on sheet1 until the value in column A is empty. In my example the status was in column B, you can change this of course.